# Pattern within a pattern?

Tags: regex

I want to capture `Alta, Utah, USA` from `asd Alta, Utah, USA qwe`. Basically I'm trying to capture places from a text. It won't be a perfect method, but the places must start with a capital and use a comma, followed by another word with a capital.

So far, I have wrote:

```
\s[A-Z][a-z]+[,]?
```

I want to do multiple words, not just the first word, `Alta`. This is my attempt to use square brackets inside other square brackets.

```
[\s[A-Z][a-z]+[,]?]+
```

But that doesn't work, so it must be syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated as per OP's comment:

```
(?:\s*[A-Z][A-Za-z]+[,\s])+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZu6ks/5)

Original Answer:

```
\b([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+),?
```

[Original Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZu6ks/4)

And you will get the names of the country in group 1 for each match

Comment: Well I don't want 3 different matches. I want to have 1 match, that is `Alta, Utah, USA`

Comment: What if the input String is like Alta, pqr bla bla USA, pql Utah bla bla is it a valid string ? if yes, then what output do you want ?

Comment: In that case, do not select anything. It is invalid input in my definition.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)(,\s*([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+))*
```

Though the requirement pointed out by @Rizwan (in his comment) is still to be understood.

[image]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5bOnkeqg-u043sbO)

Answer (score 1):

Just joining the party:

```
import re
dirty = "asd Alta, Utah, USA qwe"
p = re.compile("([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)")
re.findall(p,dirty)
```

output:

```
['Alta', 'Utah', 'USA']
```